# Add advertising box to a specific category page

Tags: categories

I need to add some ( image or texts ) on top of **one** of my categories

I thought about editing category.php, but it affects all the categories

How can I insert various static data on each category?

**EDIT**

I'm using the [twentyfourteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen) theme

Comment: This is off topic as its a theme customization question and not specific to WordPress.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: i use twentyfourteen theme , but i change a graphic of theme by myself

Comment: Sorry, only saw your update now. Please see my update

Answer (score 0):

*Just a note to potential downvoters and close voters, even though this question by itself is on topic, the reason that this being a core theme, make this even more on topic*

**EDIT**

As you are making use of the twentyfourteen theme, you have to remember this one golden rule ( and this applies to all themes and plugins that you are not the author of ), you should not make changes to the theme ( or plugin or core files ) directly. You should create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). The page in the link actually handles this part perfectly as it specifically targets the twentyfourteen theme

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can solve this by creating a category template specific to the category you want to target

Have a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display). Let's imagine you have a category with a **slug** `one` and you need to only add your box to this category, you can create a template called `category-one.php`

Now, whenever the `one` category is selected, `category-one.php` will be used. Any other category will use the normal `category.php` template

Alternatively, you can wrap your function with a `is_category( 'one' )` conditional statement when adding your box. This will make sure that only category `one` is targeted

Comment: Down vote for answering off topic questions.

Comment: You must really really be joking me. Have you actually read my answer and also read and understood the OP

Comment: @goose I'm being really really really honest and open about why i down voted your answer to a off topic question. If he's the theme Developer then it would be o.k but as a user of the theme, he should use the theme Developers forums for theme customization questions. Please do not encourage answers to off topic questions purely to gain reputation points.

Comment: Thanks for your honesty, but I really don't see how is this theme specific, even if the theme is not his own

Comment: thanks so much both of you for Take a time here and comment , I think @Goosen mentioned a very useful tips for what i ask and i will check it very soon 

@BradDalton if you see my profile you will understand that i cant give reputation to anyone cause i`m new , and maybe my Question is not about Wordpress developing but this Question maybe comes for many users and it think it`s not fully off topic 

Do you think theme Developers waste a time and answer my Question before i buy theirs themes ? it`s a joke, they never help till you buy something from them , so for free themes we are by our own !

Comment: @Arioman Your question might be in the tiniest bit borderline, if even, but it is surely not off topic. If you feel comfortable that my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer. Please take a [tour] and learn how the site operates. :-)

Comment: @BradDalton. This question was on topic from the start, and looking at all the rejected close votes enforces this. Being a core theme, twentyfourteen makes this even more on topic. I really don't see your problem here and only saw your edition to your comment now, I'm really not happy that you make accusations that I want to gain reputation "unlawfully". I don't mind the downvote, really I don't, but there is no need to make false accusations like that based on assumptions or opinion. I'm not here to fight, but please, get your facts straight before you make such accusations

Comment: @goose Looking at the history, i don't believe it. "I've paid to someone to create a theme for me. Everything works fine, expect the excerpt on category posts. What can I do? My designer is out of touch and does not answer me after recieving his money."

Comment: @Arioman You are being dishonest and telling lies to get free theme customization. You see these forums as a place to lie and manipulate people into doing your work for you for free which is why you remain anonymous. NO real name, no image, no link to a real site.